# How to resolve the Wampserver error?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I just installed WAP 2.2 d, on my local machine. It runs on Wndows 7 Starter. The installation was done smoothly. Then when I hit the URL `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gave me a message

```
**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/on this server.
```

Then after doing some research on this issue I found one solution as to make the change in file wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf
The initial lines were

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

I changed these line to following lines:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
Order Allow, Deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Then the phpMyadmin started working properly at URL `localhost/phpmyadmin`
After that I copied my directory 'XYZ' containing small project of PHP. Hit the URL `localhost/XYZ`, then it was expected to run the index.php file from the folder XYZ but it's still giving me the error

```
**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access /XYZ on this server.
```

Can you help me to resolve this issue and run the system properly. Except above change to `wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf` I've not done any change to any of configuration file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does localhost give you when you ping it from the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

You must allow access to your XYZ directory in Apache configuration file httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/XYZ">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow, Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is most likely because W7 has IPV4 and IPV6 enabled.
Apache is happy to listen to both ranges of port numbers, and by default does.

A better **more secure** solution would be:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   Require local
</Directory>
```

`Require local` is like saying `Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1` i.e. both IP Address ranges alias's for this PC.

Also if you do as you did and `Allow from all` when you decide to show a friend what you have done and open you router so the world can see your new site, they will also be given access to phpMyAdmin **making a hackers life really easy**

Secondly, you do not make the change suggested by @user4035, instead edit the httpd.conf and look for this section

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/www/">
```

Where is says,

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change it in the same way as above, to

```
Require local
```

For the same security reason as above. When the time comes to show the world your site you can add the

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/XYZ">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To allow anybody to see just that website but nothing else.